# find the serial number with criteria

Tags: excel, function, indexing, max

I have an Excel database, and they are asking me to find the 8-digit pserial value for the oldest current smoker in the survey. The person is a smoker if cigst is 4.
The pserial numbers are in column 3 and smokers are in column N.Age is column

this is the database, but there is more data inside the database:

[image]

I think the functions to use are INDEX, MAX and IF, but not sure on what order to use.

Comment: For the oldest based on a date then consider min() or minifs()

Comment: Excel is not a database. It's a spreadsheet. There is a big difference between the two, and terminology is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are several people with the same age, it is easiest to use the filter function:

```
=FILTER($C$11:$C$39;($H$11:$H$39=MAXIFS($H$11:$H$39;$N$11:$N$39;4))*($N$11:$N$39=4))
```

Maybe you have replace semicolon with comma, depending of your Excel version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however now they are asking me that if more than one individual shares this value, then present the first value that appears in the datablock. Should I change the function ?

Comment: There are several ways to do it. In the filter formula you just can add a @ after the = So it looks like this =@FILTER($C$11:$C$39;($H$11:$H$39=MAXIFS($H$11:$H$39;$N$11:$N$39;4))*($N$11:$N$39=4))

Answer (score 2):

The following should work, assuming the input data are in the range of `11-100` rows. You can adapt it to your actual range. Considering also no excel version constraint based on tags listed in the question .

```
=LET(f, FILTER(HSTACK(C11:C100, H11:H100), N11:N100=4), fa, INDEX(f,,1), 
  fb, INDEX(f,,2), TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(fa, fb=MAX(fb))))
```

You filter first a subset of **pserial** and **age** columns based on **cigst** column values equal to `4`, then just find the maximum. Preventing more than one **pserial** value correspond to the maximum age, we use `TEXTJOIN` to concatenate the result. If it is not expected for your real case, then you can remove this last step.

Comment: As always very detailed =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however now they are asking me that 
if more than one individual shares this value, then present the first value that appears in the datablock. Should I change the function ?

Comment: @irene1509 then you can use `XLOOKUP` for example: `=LET(f, FILTER(HSTACK(C11:C100, H11:H100), N11:N100=4), fa, INDEX(f,,1), fb, INDEX(f,,2), XLOOKUP(MAX(fb), fb, fa, "Not found"))`